# How to implement C# code for Order id separated by commas and range separated by hyphens, and display all info of order

Tags: c#, sql-server, listbox

Ex: 1,4-90, 292,123
It needs to display the whole order information of 
1
4,5,6....90
292
123.

Whats the gud approach to solve this.

It is similar to tracking in UPS or fedex if multiple orders are given in search box.

I meant if in a search box I giv 1,4-90, 292,123 this string the result that needs to come back is a grid representation of all the data which is corresponding to each of the order id respectively. I want to know how to parse the string into collection and send them to the database and show the information in the grid for...

1
4,5,6....90
292
123.

as a different row...from where I can generate reports too (alternative)

Comment: Are you just asking how to parse such string into a collection of numbers? If you want something more, you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```
static ArrayList list;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "1,4-90,292,123";

        string[] arr = str.Split(',');

        list = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            string tmp = arr[i];
            if (tmp.IndexOf('-') != -1)
            {
                Range(tmp);
            }
            else list.Add(int.Parse(tmp));
        }

        list.Sort();

        object[] intResult = list.ToArray();

        //print the final result
        for (int i = 0; i < intResult.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(intResult[i].ToString());
        }

        Console.Read();

    }

    static void Range(string range)
    {
        string[] tmpArr = range.Split('-');
        int stInt = int.Parse(tmpArr[0]);
        int edInt = int.Parse(tmpArr[1]);

        int[] intArr = new int[(edInt - stInt) + 1];

        for (int i = 0; stInt <= edInt; i++)
        {
            list.Add(stInt++);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why use an `ArrayList` over a `List<T>`?

Comment: You can use either way. But your one is only integer and not specific Object. I just tried that way and provided logic how to get what you want.

Comment: `List<T>` is generally preferred due to type safety. It also performs better in most cases.

Comment: this code works and it shows in the format I require. Thank you. Now I want to pass each value to a SQL query which brings the order information of each id and display the result in a grid... I prob can giv a try from here